# Splitting an array into multiple arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, split

What is the best way to split an array(mainArr) that holds 50 random integers into 5 different arrays that all contain 10 of the integers in each?

For example arr1 holds mainArr's 0-9 values, arr2 holds 10-19....

I have searched around but everything is splitting the array into two different arrays. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you do something like `int *arr1 = mainArr, *arr2 = mainArr + 10, ...`

Comment: 2 is multiple. Can't you apply the solution for "1 array to 2 arrays" to "1 array to N arrays"?

Comment: Exploit the fact is in C/C++, arrays act like pointers. Simply create 5 pointers, which point to the 0th, 10th, 20th, 30th and 40th cells in the array

Comment: It's not like Java or Python, in which array is kind of object that is defined with length that you can always query. In C/C++, you as a programmer are responsible to always know your array size. Just treat your 50-sized array as 5 10-sized arrays

Comment: @SomethingSomething but the 0th array contains all elements of mainArr?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette, yes, but who cares? Is it written anywhere that `mainArr` contains 50 cells? It is not...

Comment: No you are right. We know number of elements of each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be a little more generic:

```
int mainArr[50];
int *arr[5];

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    arr[i] = &mainArr[i*10];
```

And then access for example `mainArr[10]` as `arr[1][0]`.

Comment: I would change `&mainArr[i*10]` to `mainArr + (i * 10)`, but it's only my opinion..

Comment: @Jason What do you mean? `mainArr` has only 1 dimension. `arr[i]` accesses the ith array

Comment: This helped alot, I am new to c++ so you will have to forgive me

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, you're right.  The second array is ragged, not two dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a function that maps each index, 0..49, into another index 0..4. The obvious function is division by 10.  Modulus by 5 also works though.

```
int a[50];
int b[5][10];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  b[i/10][i%10] = a[i];
```

or

```
int a[50];
int b[5][10];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  b[i%5][i/5] = a[i];
```

See @nnn's solution for an example that re-uses the same memory.